# Q10 What is the sum of the first 45 terms of an arithmetic sequence if the sum of its 18 th and 28 th term is 36?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Q10 What is the sum of the first 45 terms of an arithmetic sequence if the sum of its 18
th and 28
th term
is 36?
A) 3240
B) 1620
C) 810
D) 405
 Please help me and explain the answers too!

Answer (score 2):

We can take $a_n=a+nd$ for some $a,d$. So $36=(a+18d)+(a+28d)$ $=2a+46d$, or $a+23d=18$. Hence the sum of the first 45 terms is $45a+d(1+2+\dots+45)=$ $45a+d\cdot23\cdot45$ $=45(a+23d)$ $=810$.

Answer (score 2):

There are $17$ terms before the $18$th term, and $17$ terms after the $28$th term, for the sum under consideration. So we're looking at a "first+last" trick, and the sum is $$\frac{45}{2}\times 36 = 810$$

Comment: Whoa, that's cute!  I got caught up in algebraically solving equations.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest arithmetic progression satisfying the given condition is the constant progression with all $45$ terms equal to $18.$ The sum of that progression is $45\times18=810.$ If we assume there's enough information to deduce the answer, that must be it. That's kind of a cheat, but good enough for a multiple choice test.

The reason the sum of the $18$th and $28$th terms *are* enough to determine the sum is the symmetric placement of those two terms about the center of the progression:
$$36=a_{18}+a_{28}=a_{17}+a_{29}=a_{16}+a_{30}=\cdots=a_1+a_{45}$$
and
$$36=a_{18}+a_{28}=a_{19}+a_{27}=\cdots=a_{22}+a_{24}=2\cdot a_{23},$$
so
$$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{45}=(a_1+a_{45})+(a_2+a_{44})+\cdots+(a_{22}+a_{24})+a_{23}=22\cdot36+18=810.$$